# How to set or get write permission on Google+ for post on google+ ?

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-oauth

We have tried to set/get write permission bellow:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.read
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.read
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.write
```

for posting on google plus, but I am not able to post on google+ wall.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: @jww how is the google+ api not programing?  This is defiantly a programing question.

Comment: @DaImTo - Perhaps you should show your code to remove ambiguity.

Comment: @jww this is not my question.  So not sure what code you think I should show.     You do realize that these are Google OAuth scopes and not random urls right?  There is enough code there to identify the problem as it is.

Answer (score 2):

[Google plus API](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/) is a read only API.  You can NOT post to Google plus (website / google+ wall)programmatically.

It really wont matter what scope you send your not going to post to a wall.   If you are looking at activates they are also not posting to a wall.

Activates are internal based upon your application.  If you install your application and your friend does you will both see the posts but no one else as they are only view able via your application.   They are not posted publicly on the google plus website.

Comment: We are able to post on Google+ using Google domain account.

=>Once we need to create google domain account.
=> Create GSuit account.
=> Using it we can access Google admin account and using it we can set permission for google post and it will connect with google console using service id then after we are able to post on google+ wall.

Answer (score 0):

We can able to post on Google+ Wall.

Once we will need top create Domain account for google so we will get write permission for posting.

I have already done it.